# JavaScript cannot get firstChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get first child of my div "tick_list" to insert new element but it returns undefined.

```
$(function() {
   var tick_list = $('#tick_list');

    socket.on('tick', function(data){
        console.log(tick_list.firstElementChild);
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tick_list` is a jQuery object which does not have `firstElementChild` property.

You could use `tick_list.children().eq(0)` to get the first child (still a jQuery object).

There are many ways to get the first child, and here is a **[jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/getting-first-child-element-using-jquery/3)** for them:

Comment: `.eq()` returns a jQuery object... `.get()` ?

Comment: `get()` returns the native HTML DOM element (clearly explained in the documentation ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   var tick_list = $('#tick_list');

    socket.on('tick', function(data){
        console.log(tick_list.eq(0));
    });
});
```

Comment: `.eq(0)` returns the first element in the collection tick_list ... not it's children

Comment: `.eq()` returns a jQuery object... don't confuse between `.get(0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   var tick_list = $('#tick_list');

    socket.on('tick', function(data){
        console.log(tick_list.children(':first'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the children() and first() jquery methods

```
$(function() {
   var tick_list = $('#tick_list');

    socket.on('tick', function(data){
        console.log(tick_list.children().first());
    });
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/children/

https://api.jquery.com/first/

Answer (score 0):

`tick_list` is a jQuery object so you can't directly access dom properties using member operators.

You use use .prop() method

```
tick_list.prop('firstElementChild')
```

or access the underlying dom element using index of .get()

```
tick_list[0].firstElementChild
```